# Customize google places to find restaurants nearby

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am building an android app to find all the restaurant nearby. i m taking the help of google places api to do so but i am not able to customize it to shown only restaurants. So please help and thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnConnectionFailedListener {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Button btn; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();

   PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {

                                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Place   " + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this using

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY

For more reference goto,
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search